# What is the difference between ingress and service mesh in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, servicemesh

Can someone help me to understand if service mesh itself is a type of ingress or if there is any difference between service mesh and ingress?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An "Ingress" is responsible for Routing Traffic into your Cluster (from the [Docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/): *An API object that manages external access to the services in a cluster, typically HTTP.*)

On the other side, a Service-Mesh is a tool that adds proxy-Containers as Sidecars to your Pods and Routs traffic between your Pods through those proxy-Containers.

use-Cases for Service-Meshes are i.E.

- distributed tracing
- secure (SSL) connections between pods
- resilience (service-mesh can reroute traffic from failed requests)
- network-performance-monitoring

Comment: Thanks, @Alex, this helped me to understand the difference between the purpose of existence of these both Kubernetes objects

Comment: also, I like this one-liner - "An Ingress is the entry point of a service mesh.", which was shared as another answer prior (as it helps to understand where exactly these two objects reside in the Kubernetes ecosystem)